# root is completely out of room. At 100%

Tags: server, root, disk, disk-usage

I see many similar posts, but all of these suggest running something like:

```
du -hx / | sort -n
```

Which might help me, but any command on this server just comes back with

```
sort: write failed: /tmp/sortc0c7gF: No space left on device
```

So, I have rebooted and it still comes up 100%. How can I axe enough stuff just to come up for air! Thanks. Oh here is the result of df, but I'm not sure how helpful that is!

[just took a screen clip since I could not paste the result with proper formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5WLu.png)

I should add this is a headless server running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I do have physical access, but if I could do this through an SSH session in the terminal, that would be the best!

I tried running this. "sudo du -h --max-depth=1"  Do you think the problem might be those process? If so, how can I get at them? I have rebooted the server a few times.

[Here is a screen shot of a du command looking at one layer deep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6C5R.png)

Comment: I would start with `sudo apt-get clean`. That safely cleans out `/var/cache/apt` (which can get very large).

Comment: Thank you for responding! I had tried that, and I did again about 1/2hr ago based on your recommendation. Checking with df still shows 100% again :(

Comment: just found and did this  dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge ' it is running and mentions it will romove about 5.5 MBs so that is a start!

Comment: ugh. then did apt-get autoclean and apt-get autoremove. Nothing. I am still so full it reports 100%. I think this happened when trying to copy a massive amount from a windows machine to a share mounted on a different drive from root. The copy was canceled. Maybe it 'cached' on the root drive? Somewhere? Somehow locked out?

Comment: Your first picture shows that `/` has a size >200 GB, but the `du` command output sums up to around 10 GB only. Possibly you have hidden data at the mount points. Try to `umount` what you have mounted on /media, then do `sudo du -ms /media`.

Comment: I think you are on to something. However, I cannot umount one of my shares. The one my son was copying to when this all went sideways. I tried sudo umount. It says it's busy. I did sudo lsof | grep '/media' then sudo pkill whatever was accessing. However, they come back on immediately and then I cannot umount. I definitely think this is tied to that failed copy, but I do not know why my '/' would be full. The copy was coming from Windows and using smbd

Answer (score 0):

Found it! @muclux was on the right track. In this system I have 3 HDs. One for the OS, one for my shares, and one that is a lazy back-up. I run rsync commands every hour to sync over from the shares. However, when I run rsync I just use the /media/backup_hd mount point. Somehow my actual drive was unmounted and so the rsync command tried to copy my files to the directory which is just a part of the root hard drive. I do not know how it was umounted but when I pulled the OS drive and put it into another system that is where I found all the junk.

My problem now is the OS will not boot. I think I corrupted my OS drive somehow. Not sure how, but it just blinks. I bet I wrecked GRUB somehow. Anyway, this problem is solved. I will look up how to run rsync to the drive not the mount point or something to avoid this in the future. Wild really. Thanks to everyone who read through this.